# how to make object keep moving up

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game with Python. I have a spaceship in this game. The spaceship can move to the left and to the right and it is supposed to shoot bullets from its x-position and it is supposed to fire the bullets up. I am able to move the spaceship and I am able to put it on the screen. The problem is that I am not able to fire the bullet from the spaceship's x-position and I am not able to make the bullet move up. Can somebody help me with this? Please post simple code too if possible.

Here's the code:

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
screen_length = 512
screen_width = 288
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_length))
bg = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Anonymous\Downloads\space game folder\space background3.png').convert()
bg = pygame.transform.scale2x(bg)
spaceship = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Soorya\Anonymous\space game folder\spaceship.png').convert()
missile = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Soorya\Anonymous\space game folder\bullet2.png').convert()
x = 130
y = 480
z = 460
velocity = 30
spaceship_rect = spaceship.get_rect(center=(x, y))
spaceship_x_pos = spaceship_rect.left + 170
bullet_speed = 10
missile_rect = missile.get_rect(center=(round(spaceship_x_pos // 2), z))
spaceship_direction = 10
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            sys.exit(0)
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 288:
        x += velocity
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 0:
        x -= velocity
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        bg.blit(missile, missile_rect)
screen.fill(0)
screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
screen.blit(spaceship, (x, y))
pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(120)
```

Comment: You need to update y coordinate based on key.up/down in while loop.

Comment: How can I do that

Comment: the same as you do with x coordinate but with different key

Comment: But that will move up only once right? I want the bullet to keep moving up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your indentation is not right.

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            sys.exit(0)
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 288:
        x += velocity
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 0:
        x -= velocity
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        bg.blit(missile, missile_rect)
screen.fill(0) # THIS
screen.blit(bg, (0, 0)) #THIS
screen.blit(spaceship, (x, y)) #THIS
pygame.display.update() #THIS
clock.tick(120) #THIS
```

The lines where i commented this have to be indented like this:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            sys.exit(0)
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 288:
        x += velocity
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 0:
        x -= velocity
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        bg.blit(missile, missile_rect)
    screen.fill(0)
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(spaceship, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```

That's because you want to do those things every single frame while the game is running. One more thing, you are filling the screen with black in line `screen.fill(0)`, which is not necessary since you are already rendering a background image, so you basically cannot see it. With that being said, i recommend taking an object oriented approach as well because you wont get very far without it. Also, set velocity to like 0.5 or something. Its currently 30, which means 30 pixels every frame and that's not what you want.

Now to fire bullets. What you are doing right now wont work because you are only "blitting" a missile if space is pressed. Below i wrote a separate code for you that only fires missiles, so hopefully its clear and you can implement in your own code.

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()

d = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))

# WE WILL USE FIRING BOOLEAN TO KEEP TRACK OF IF WE ARE FIRING MISSILES
firing = False
missile = pygame.Surface((10, 50))

while True:

    d.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type  == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    # Assign initial positions only if it isnt firing
    if not firing:
        missilex = 600  # This is the initial position of the missile. This will be
        missiley = 500  # your player position in your game

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_SPACE]: # if space pressed set firing to true
        firing = True

    # if firing is true, we want to display the missile and move it.
    if firing:
        d.blit(missile, (missilex, missiley))
        missiley -= 1

    # if missile is off the screen, set firing to false so it resets to initial position (600, 500).
    if missiley < -20:
        firing = False

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you are approaching it doesn't seem right to me, unless ofc that isn't your whole code. But you are using the same variable to represent the x and y coordinate of your bullet and the spaceship. You want to bullet to move independently from the space ship. So if you change the variable y in your code, that will move space ship up too, and same with the x variable.

What you need to do is to create 2 separate classes. One for you bullet, and the other for the space ship. Here is a simple example of its implementation, which you can improve upon by adding whatever features you want later.

```
class Spaceship:
    image = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Soorya\Anonymous\space game folder\spaceship.png').convert()

    def __init__(self, x, y, vel):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.vel = vel

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(Spaceship.image, (self.x, self.y))

class Bullet:
    image = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Soorya\Anonymous\space game folder\bullet2.png').convert()
    bullet_list = []  # holds the list of bullets in the screen

    def __init__(self, x, y, vel):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.vel = vel
        Bullet.bullet_list.append(self)

    def move(self):
        self.y -= self.vel
        if self.y < 0:  # remove bullet if it goes beyond screen
            Bullet.bullet_list.remove(self)

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(Bullet.image, (self.x, self.y))

spaceship = Spaceship(130, 480, 30)

# set up screen and bg as before
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            sys.exit(0)
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 288:
        spaceship.x += spaceship.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 0:
        spaceship.x -= spaceship.vel
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:  # create a bullet if space is pressed
        Bullet(spaceship.x, spaceship.y, 10)

    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    spaceship.draw()
    for bullet in Bullet.bullet_list():
        bullet.move()  # actually moves the bullet on each iteration of the loop
        bullet.draw()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```

Important note for future if you want to create games, **make everything object oriented** lol. Trust me, it will make your life a whole lot easier. Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: What is spaceship = Spaceship(120, 430, 30)

Comment: that is you creating a new object of the space ship class.

Comment: what is (120, 430, 30)?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDa-Z5JzLYM this youtuber explains OOP well if you want to check it out. It's an important and a fundamental concept you should try to learn.

Comment: oh my bad, that is your x, y and velocity values. I accidently used the wrong ones. I'll edit it now.

Comment: what is Bullets.bullet_list(). There is an error telling that it is an unresolved reference. btw ur a real legend dude

Comment: oh sorry, that's a typo on my part. the class name is 'Bullet' not 'Bullets' so if you change the spelling it should be fine. Sorry I didn't run my code to check for quick errors, but it should work other wise. And thanks :) glad to help

Comment: The bullet is not moving up

Comment: can you edit the question with your new code so that I can see?

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to help. You should mark an answer as accepted if it helps answer your question so that others can use it too.